# Get SPF records from a Domain

Tags: c#, asp.net, spf

What are the ways to Check SPF records on a domain?

There is a website where i can do it manually using - http://www.mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx

How can i do it via ASP.NET and C#? Basically i want to verify/check SPF records on a domain if its supporting out own mail web server.

Answer (score 16):

I have the same problem, and managed to find <s>two</s> three solutions:

#### The `nslookup` solution

You can get the SPF by typing the following command in the command line:

```
nslookup -type=TXT <hostname>
```

You can automate this in C# using [`System.Diagonstics.Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx), as described in [this blog post](http://www.robertsindall.co.uk/blog/getting-dns-txt-record-using-c-sharp/).

#### The DNS.NET Resolver project

I found [this CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23673/DNS-NET-Resolver-C) about DNS resolution. It comes with demo project. I ran the project and got the following result for `stackexchange.com`:

[image: DNS Dig screeenshot]

***Note:*** Make sure that the *QType* field is set to *TXT* before you press the *Send* button

The section highlighted in yellow represents the SPF record. I haven't yet dug into the code to see how it's done, but this seems like a good alternative to the `nslookup` solution above.

#### [Update] The ARSoft.Tools.Net project

If all you need to do is check whether a domain supports a mail server, you can use the [ARSoft.Tools.Net](http://arsofttoolsnet.codeplex.com/) library (also available as a [NuGet Package](http://nuget.org/packages/ARSoft.Tools.Net)).

After installing the package, I managed to perform the SPF check with this code:

```cs
var spfValidator = new ARSoft.Tools.Net.Spf.SpfValidator();

var mailIpAddress = IPAddress.Parse("X.X.X.X");
var domain = "example.com";
var senderAddress = "sender@example.com";

ARSoft.Tools.Net.Spf.SpfQualifier result = 
    spfValidator.CheckHost(mailIpAddress, domain, senderAddress);
```

Comment: Hi W0lf, what does "X.X.X.X" in IPAddress.Parse(), stands for?

Comment: This is working now but i have 4 email webserver's and i wanna test either of these are trusted by the other companies to send email's on behalf of our webserver. How can i do this? Let me know your thoughts on this.

Comment: @nimi the `X.X.X.X` is a placeholder for the real IP you want to test.

Comment: @nimi if you have multiple Mail Servers (meaning more IPs to test), simply iterate through the available IPs and run the above check for each of them.

Comment: I have created a sample project and is working fine. But when i add the same in my project, i am getting some wiered error, ARSoft.Tools.Net.Spf.SpfQualifier.TempError. I dont understand  why i am getting tis error. Could you please let me know what could be the issue. I have used the above code.

Comment: @nimi I'm not sure what it means either, except that an error occurred while performing the check (RFC docs link: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4408#section-2.5.6). You might want to retry - there might have been a network/DNS error

Comment: Really nice. What about DKIM validation. Can we use same library for check Dkim ?

Answer (score 6):

Even though .NET has a lot of support for networking including doing host name to address mapping it lacks a general way to query DNS.

However, you can use P/Invoke to call the [DnsQuery function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682016%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) directly. The API is somewhat cumbersome but it is not impossible to create the correct P/Invoke signature for your requirement.

A SPF record is stored as a TXT record in DNS. The corresponding structure you will have to work with is the [DNS_TXT_DATA structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682109%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). If you can find [an example of querying a MX record](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/dnsapi.dnsquery) you can reuse the code and use `DNS_TYPE_TEXT` for the query type and unmarshal the data to a `DNS_TXT_DATA` structure.

Or you could just use this code:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public String DnsGetTxtRecord(String name) {
  const Int16 DNS_TYPE_TEXT = 0x0010;
  const Int32 DNS_QUERY_STANDARD = 0x00000000;
  const Int32 DNS_ERROR_RCODE_NAME_ERROR = 9003;
  const Int32 DNS_INFO_NO_RECORDS = 9501;
  var queryResultsSet = IntPtr.Zero;
  try {
    var dnsStatus = DnsQuery(
      name,
      DNS_TYPE_TEXT,
      DNS_QUERY_STANDARD,
      IntPtr.Zero,
      ref queryResultsSet,
      IntPtr.Zero
    );
    if (dnsStatus == DNS_ERROR_RCODE_NAME_ERROR || dnsStatus == DNS_INFO_NO_RECORDS)
      return null;
    if (dnsStatus != 0)
      throw new Win32Exception(dnsStatus);
    DnsRecordTxt dnsRecord;
    for (var pointer = queryResultsSet; pointer != IntPtr.Zero; pointer = dnsRecord.pNext) {
      dnsRecord = (DnsRecordTxt) Marshal.PtrToStructure(pointer, typeof(DnsRecordTxt));
      if (dnsRecord.wType == DNS_TYPE_TEXT) {
        var lines = new List<String>();
        var stringArrayPointer = pointer
          + Marshal.OffsetOf(typeof(DnsRecordTxt), "pStringArray").ToInt32();
        for (var i = 0; i < dnsRecord.dwStringCount; ++i) {
          var stringPointer = (IntPtr) Marshal.PtrToStructure(stringArrayPointer, typeof(IntPtr));
          lines.Add(Marshal.PtrToStringUni(stringPointer));
          stringArrayPointer += IntPtr.Size;
        }
        return String.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines);
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
  finally {
    const Int32 DnsFreeRecordList = 1;
    if (queryResultsSet != IntPtr.Zero)
      DnsRecordListFree(queryResultsSet, DnsFreeRecordList);
  }
}

[DllImport("Dnsapi.dll", EntryPoint = "DnsQuery_W", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
static extern Int32 DnsQuery(String lpstrName, Int16 wType, Int32 options, IntPtr pExtra, ref IntPtr ppQueryResultsSet, IntPtr pReserved);

[DllImport("Dnsapi.dll")]
static extern void DnsRecordListFree(IntPtr pRecordList, Int32 freeType);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
struct DnsRecordTxt {
  public IntPtr pNext;
  public String pName;
  public Int16 wType;
  public Int16 wDataLength;
  public Int32 flags;
  public Int32 dwTtl;
  public Int32 dwReserved;
  public Int32 dwStringCount;
  public String pStringArray;
}
```

Comment: +1 This is great!  I've tested your code and it works fine. However, in my case I'm still going to use the ARSoft.Tools.Net because it also does the parsing/validation.

Comment: +1 Hi Martin. Thanks! Very helpful. But there is a small bug in it. Long TXT records (dnsRecord.dwStringCount > 1) will result in multiple records (aka lines) in your code. But its easy to fix. So thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Building on [the answer by Martin Liversage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11884174/358336),  I've added some comments that explain what's going on, and adjusted to return multiple records if they exist.

My example also concatenates multiple strings in a TXT record rather than separating by line breaks.

I don't know if the `if (dnsRecord.wType == DNS_TYPE_TEXT)` line is really necessary considering that constraint is in the arguments to the `DnsQuery` function, but I preserved it from Martin's answer anyway.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

namespace Util
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/11884174 (Martin Liversage)
    /// </summary>
    class DnsInterop
    {
        private const short DNS_TYPE_TEXT = 0x0010;
        private const int DNS_QUERY_STANDARD = 0x00000000;
        private const int DNS_ERROR_RCODE_NAME_ERROR = 9003;
        private const int DNS_INFO_NO_RECORDS = 9501;


        public static IEnumerable<string> GetTxtRecords(string domain)
        {
            var results = new List<string>();
            var queryResultsSet = IntPtr.Zero;
            DnsRecordTxt dnsRecord;

            try
            {
                // get all text records
                // pointer to results is returned in queryResultsSet
                var dnsStatus = DnsQuery(
                  domain,
                  DNS_TYPE_TEXT,
                  DNS_QUERY_STANDARD,
                  IntPtr.Zero,
                  ref queryResultsSet,
                  IntPtr.Zero
                );

                // return null if no records or DNS lookup failed
                if (dnsStatus == DNS_ERROR_RCODE_NAME_ERROR
                    || dnsStatus == DNS_INFO_NO_RECORDS)
                {
                    return null;
                }

                // throw an exception if other non success code
                if (dnsStatus != 0)
                    throw new Win32Exception(dnsStatus);

                // step through each result
                for (
                    var pointer = queryResultsSet; 
                    pointer != IntPtr.Zero; 
                    pointer = dnsRecord.pNext)
                {
                    dnsRecord = (DnsRecordTxt)
                        Marshal.PtrToStructure(pointer, typeof(DnsRecordTxt));

                    if (dnsRecord.wType == DNS_TYPE_TEXT)
                    {
                        var builder = new StringBuilder();

                        // pointer to array of pointers
                        // to each string that makes up the record
                        var stringArrayPointer = pointer + Marshal.OffsetOf(
                            typeof(DnsRecordTxt), "pStringArray").ToInt32();

                        // concatenate multiple strings in the case of long records
                        for (var i = 0; i < dnsRecord.dwStringCount; ++i)
                        {
                            var stringPointer = (IntPtr)Marshal.PtrToStructure(
                                stringArrayPointer, typeof(IntPtr));

                            builder.Append(Marshal.PtrToStringUni(stringPointer));
                            stringArrayPointer += IntPtr.Size;
                        }

                        results.Add(builder.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (queryResultsSet != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    DnsRecordListFree(queryResultsSet, 
                        (int)DNS_FREE_TYPE.DnsFreeRecordList);
                }
            }

            return results;
        }


        [DllImport("Dnsapi.dll", EntryPoint = "DnsQuery_W", 
            ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, 
            SetLastError = true)]
        static extern int DnsQuery(string lpstrName, short wType, int options, 
            IntPtr pExtra, ref IntPtr ppQueryResultsSet, IntPtr pReserved);


        [DllImport("Dnsapi.dll")]
        static extern void DnsRecordListFree(IntPtr pRecordList, int freeType);


        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        struct DnsRecordTxt
        {
            public IntPtr pNext;
            public string pName;
            public short wType;
            public short wDataLength;
            public int flags;
            public int dwTtl;
            public int dwReserved;
            public int dwStringCount;
            public string pStringArray;
        }


        enum DNS_FREE_TYPE
        {
            DnsFreeFlat = 0,
            DnsFreeRecordList = 1,
            DnsFreeParsedMessageFields = 2
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to do a DNS request asking for the MX/SPF record of the domain.  There's a few examples of doing this in C# around.  There's a library at http://mailsystem.codeplex.com/ that has a `Validator` class with `GetMxRecords` to do this that you might find useful

Comment: I wanted to get SPF records, not MX Records. MX records does not give what i want, i want SPF records.

Comment: @nimi  You could have asked that in the original question instead of completely re-writing the question.  SPF is just a DNS record, you should be able to query it the same as an SPF record.

Answer (score 0):

For what is worth - MailBee's .NET Objects support this as well.  I only say this because we already owned this component and I was about to implement something else when I found this goodie already baked into what we had.

http://www.afterlogic.com/mailbee-net/docs/filter_spam_with_dns.html

Answer (score 0):

We tried to use @martin-liversage's answer, but after some time running on hundrets of domains it failed on some memory problem. (Maybe there was some invalid/another type DNS record?)
So i studied this exact WINAPI functions and structures used in this case and edited the solution acordingly.

*Links to WINAPI documentation are included in code.*

So here's our **improved code**, that's working 100% even in our case:

```
public String GetSpfRecord(String domain)
{
    // Definition of DNS params
    const Int16 DNS_TYPE_TXT = 0x0010;
    const Int32 DNS_QUERY_STANDARD = 0x00000001;
    const Int32 DNS_ERROR_RCODE_NAME_ERROR = 9003;
    const Int32 DNS_INFO_NO_RECORDS = 9501;

    DnsRecordA dnsRecord;
    var queryResultsSet = IntPtr.Zero;

    try
    {
        var dnsStatus = DnsQuery(
          domain,
          DNS_TYPE_TXT,
          DNS_QUERY_STANDARD,
          IntPtr.Zero,
          ref queryResultsSet,
          IntPtr.Zero
        );

        if (dnsStatus == DNS_ERROR_RCODE_NAME_ERROR || dnsStatus == DNS_INFO_NO_RECORDS)
            return null;

        if (dnsStatus != 0)
            throw new Win32Exception(dnsStatus);

        for (IntPtr pointer = queryResultsSet; pointer != IntPtr.Zero; pointer = dnsRecord.pNext)
        {
            // Copies data from memory (size of DnsRecordA) from adress pointer to new alocated memory and creates instance of pointer to this place.
            dnsRecord = (DnsRecordA)Marshal.PtrToStructure(pointer, typeof(DnsRecordA));

            // pokud se jedná o typ TXT
            if (dnsRecord.wType == DNS_TYPE_TXT)
            {
                // get pointer to informations in "Data" property (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/windns/ns-windns-dns_recorda)
                var dataPointer = pointer + Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(DnsRecordA));

                // Get the txtData
                var txtData = (DNS_TXT_DATAA)Marshal.PtrToStructure(dataPointer, typeof(DNS_TXT_DATAA));
                if (txtData.dwStringCount >= 1)
                {
                    string line = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(txtData.pStringArray[0]);

                    // only if record starts with "v=spf" (Getting only SPF records)
                    // Getting only first (here is always maximum of 1 record) and returning whole line
                    if (line.StartsWith("v=spf") && string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
                    {
                        return line;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // no SPF record - returning null
        return null;
    }
    finally
    {
        const Int32 DnsFreeRecordList = 1;

        // always release the memory alocated for list of dns records
        if (queryResultsSet != IntPtr.Zero)
            DnsRecordListFree(queryResultsSet, DnsFreeRecordList);
    }
}

// https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/windns/nf-windns-dnsquery_a
[DllImport("Dnsapi.dll", EntryPoint = "DnsQuery_W", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
static extern Int32 DnsQuery(String lpstrName, Int16 wType, Int32 options, IntPtr pExtra, ref IntPtr ppQueryResultsSet, IntPtr pReserved);

// https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/windns/nf-windns-dnsrecordlistfree
[DllImport("Dnsapi.dll")]
static extern void DnsRecordListFree(IntPtr pRecordList, Int32 freeType);

// https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/windns/ns-windns-dns_recorda
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
struct DnsRecordA
{
    public IntPtr pNext;
    public String pName;
    public Int16 wType;
    public Int16 wDataLength;
    public Int32 flags;
    public Int32 dwTtl;
    public Int32 dwReserved;

    // Commented, because i'm getting this value dynamicaly (it can also be another structure type which might cause some problems)
    //public DNS_TXT_DATA Data;
}

// https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/windns/ns-windns-dns_txt_dataa
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct DNS_TXT_DATAA
{
    /// DWORD->unsigned int
    public uint dwStringCount;

    /// PSTR[1]
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 1, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.SysUInt)]
    internal IntPtr[] pStringArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on DnsDig project I created a DLL which can be used on any .net (vb , c#, forms, web. etc..) project

https://devselz.com/software/devselz_dnsdig_dns-txt-etc-query-domain-register.zip

Download the DLL , unzip, and Add as reference to your project (if website place on root/bin folder):

#### DnsDig.dll

#### nunit.framework.dll

(126KB in total)

Then use this example as for an ASP.Ne website (vb.net code)

```
Imports DnsDig
Imports Heijden.DNS
Partial Class lib_u_l_Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Public Resolver As Resolver
    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Resolver = New Resolver
        Dim SW As New System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch
        SW.Start()
        Dim DNSResponse As Heijden.DNS.Response = Resolver.Query(Request.QueryString("d"), QType.SPF, QClass.ANY)
        SW.Stop()
        If DNSResponse.header.ANCOUNT > 0 Then
            For Each answerRR As AnswerRR In DNSResponse.Answers
                Response.Write("<br/>" & answerRR.ToString)
            Next
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

RESULTS:
https://yourwebsiteusingabovedlls.com/anyplacewhereabovecode/?d=goodyes.com

will write

goodyes.com. 3535 IN TXT "google-site-verification=IMw-tL0VWgMJbtcRgt_bu5UaVwpbNb94dvcOSObooa4"
goodyes.com. 3535 IN TXT "v=spf1 include:_spf.buzondecorreo.com ~all"

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the package [DnsClient.NET](https://dnsclient.michaco.net/) ([Github-Repo](https://github.com/MichaCo/DnsClient.NET)).

This library is able to do high performant DNS lookups as well as lookups for SPF-entries.

Example code for SPF-lookup:

```
var domainName = "example.domain";
var lookup = new LookupClient();
var result = await lookup.QueryAsync(domainName, QueryType.TXT).ConfigureAwait(false);

var records = result.Answers.OfType<TxtRecord>().ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

Funny how all the websites has this wrong

SPF is not TXT

you can have a txt record with no SPF and SPF with no  TXT, so a TXT lookup will not show the SPF

Comment: Not anymore.  SPF type resource records were deprecated in [RFC7208](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7208).  See section 3.1 for the reasoning, but the TLDR is that nobody was adopting it because nobody had a mail server that would do SPF type DNS requests.  Everybody implemented TXT only.